# Where can PCollection class be found in python's Apache Beam library?

Tags: python-3.x, apache-beam

I want the class for type info in some of my functions. For example:

```
def process_words(words: PCollection, max_len: int) -> PCollection:
    some code...
    ...
    return processed_words
```

Now, for defining the type PCollection, I will need to import the class. From where should I import?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find it in the API documentation on the Beam site. It is [apache_beam.pvalue.PCollection](https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.27.0/apache_beam.pvalue.html#apache_beam.pvalue.PCollection).

Comment: FWIW I agree that it is sort of random which classes end up in which file. This is why having a very shallow namespace is better, and why Java chose to have filenames exactly match class names.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I totally agree with you.